# Listen for dispatched action in Redux

Tags: javascript, redux, ngredux

I'm wondering if there's a way to listen for an action that's been successfully dispatched in redux?

In the ngxs state management library for Angular, I can do the following:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.actions$
    .pipe(
      ofActionSuccessful(AddedThingToDo),
      map((event: AddedThingToDo) => event.thingToDo),
      tap(thingToDo => console.log('Action was successfully dispatched'))
    )
   .subscribe();
}
```

Where I can then perform an action when I know that `AddedThingToDo` has been successfully dispatched.  This could be something like closing a modal, or perhaps dispatching another action.

I'm using `ng-redux` for Angular 1.x, however I think the principle should remain the same that it would for react redux.

The only way I've been getting around it is with a callback in my actions, but it feels very wrong:

```
export const addThingToDo = (model: IThingToDo, onSuccess?: (model: IThingToDo) => void) =>
  async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    dispatch(addingThingToDo());
    try {
      const createdItem = await api.post<IThingToDo>(url, model);
      dispatch(addedThingToDo(createdItem));
      if (onSuccess) {
        onSuccess(createdItem);
      }
    }
    catch (ex) {
      dispatch(addThingToDoFailure(ex));
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `redux-thunk` supports returning promises, so I can just return a promise rather than use a callback method.

```
export const addThingToDo = (model: IThingToDo) =>
  async (dispatch: Dispatch): Promise<IThingToDo> =>
    await new Promise<IThingToDo>(async (resolve, reject) => {
      dispatch(addingThingToDo());
      try {
        const newItem = await api.post<IThingToDo>(url, model);
        dispatch(addedThingToDo(newItem));
        resolve(newItem);
      } catch (ex) {
        dispatch(addThingToDoFailure(ex));
        reject(ex);
      }
    });


this.addThingToDo(thingToDo)
  .then(t => navigateTo(`/things-to-do/${t.id}`));
```